# Correct implementation of 2d vector population

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a constructor and a method in an implementation file:

```
Boggle::Boggle(std::string boardString){

dim = sqrt(boardString.size());
vector<vector<char> > grid(dim, vector<char>(dim));
int co = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = boardString[co];
        co++;
    }    
}
}

void Boggle::printMe() {

for (auto inner : grid)
{
    for (auto item : inner)
    {
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

The program executes, but doesn't do anything. As you can see I have sized my vector when I declared it. I believe the issue lies in my logic of assigning a character to a vector from a string perhaps.

Comment: _"I believe the issue lies in my logic of assigning a character to a vector from a string perhaps."_ Fortunately you don't need to rely in _belief_. You can verify your assumptions running your code in the debugger, step through it line by line and watch the variables to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suppose it is a problem with the method then. The vector populates fine it seems until the second line of the printMe method, then it seems to say size = 0;

Comment: At least post a [mcve] if you want to get an answer why it behaves that way here. Hint: `vector<vector<char> > grid(dim, vector<char>(dim));` is a local variable in your constructor body. It will be gone after the constructor was called.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in comments your vector `grid` is local to your function. You mostly likely wanted to use a class variable but ended up creating a local variable. You can use `resize` to set the dimensions of your grid. Also its better to `ceil` the `sqrt` to make sure that we are not missing any characters.

Example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // Avoid this

class Boggle{

    public:
    int dim;
    vector<vector<char>> grid;

    Boggle(string boardString);
    void printMe();

};


Boggle::Boggle (std::string boardString)
{

  dim = ceil(sqrt(boardString.size ()));
  grid.resize(dim, vector <char>(dim));
  int co = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      grid[i][j] = boardString[co];
      co++;
    }
  }
}

void Boggle::printMe ()
{

    for (auto inner:grid) {

        for (auto item:inner)
        {
          cout << item << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){

    Boggle boggle("hello world");

    boggle.printMe();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:
`h e l l`

`o   w o`

`r l d`